# Symfony output of data in date grouped tables

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am querying my database for information which is returned in an array of objects in the following format:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  Object
        (
            [id] => 54
            [cost] => 14.99
            [date] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2015-04-19 20:20:00
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => UTC
                )
        )
    [1] =>  Object
        (
            [id] => 55
            [cost] => 4.99
            [date] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2015-04-22 20:20:00
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => UTC
                )
        )
    [2] => Object
        (
            ........
```

Alot of the objects have dates on the same dates. What I'm trying to accomplish is printing all the objects data in multiple tabular format. Each table has to be headed by a unique date - and that's where the challenge is. **How do I group all the data returned by my database query into an array indexed by unique dates?**

I know I can iterate the output above and insert each object into an array with the correct date index. However, that will become inefficient when there are thousands of records to process each time the page needs to be reloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example from doctrine document:

The INDEX BY construct is nothing that directly translates into SQL but that affects object and array hydration. After each FROM and JOIN clause you specify by which field this class should be indexed in the result. By default a result is incremented by numerical keys starting with 0. However with INDEX BY you can specify any other column to be the key of your result, it really only makes sense with primary or unique fields though:

```
SELECT u.id, u.status, upper(u.name) nameUpper FROM User u INDEX BY u.id
JOIN u.phonenumbers p INDEX BY p.phonenumber
```

Returns an array of the following kind, indexed by both user-id then phonenumber-id:

```
array
  0 =>
    array
      1 =>
        object(stdClass)[299]
          public '__CLASS__' => string 'Doctrine\Tests\Models\CMS\CmsUser' (length=33)
          public 'id' => int 1
          ..
      'nameUpper' => string 'ROMANB' (length=6)
  1 =>
    array
      2 =>
        object(stdClass)[298]
          public '__CLASS__' => string 'Doctrine\Tests\Models\CMS\CmsUser' (length=33)
          public 'id' => int 2
          ...
      'nameUpper' => string 'JWAGE' (length=5)
```

[doctrine document](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#using-index-by)

Comment: Thanks @ghanbari. I knew it had to come down to how to retrieve the data from the database.