# Mysql alternative to index by for efficient database data grouping on non-unique field

Tags: mysql, symfony, indexing, grouping

My mysql database table has multiple entries with the following structure:

```
id, title, date, time
```

There are presently 30 entries in the table and some of those share a common date.

What I'm trying to accomplish is retrieving the database data in such a way that will group them under common dates. So, all entries that share the same date will be grouped in an array indexed by that common date.

In [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737359/symfony-output-of-data-in-date-grouped-tables), I learnt INDEX BY is great for what I'm trying to achieve but it works only/best on unique fields.

**So, I am just curious if there is anything else that could help efficiently group my database entrie.**

Comment: i'd suggest starting here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html. For 30 entries tho it should be lightning fast even without any optimisations.

Comment: 30 rows in a table do not need any additional effort for performance.  A basic SQL query doing what you want should be amply efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your input. You are absolutely right 30 rows does not constitute a lot but that will change rapidly once it's in active use. Which is why I'm looking for an efficient solution from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date, GROUP_CONCAT(title)
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY date
    ORDER BY date;
```

Don't worry about performance until you have thousands of rows.